# What does “in the rearview mirror” mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

In "Finders Keepers" by Stephen King, there is a character named Andy Halliday and he says his lovelife has been in the rearview mirror for over 15 years.

What does “in the rearview mirror” mean in this context?

Comment: It means it's long behind him. That is, he hasn't had a love life in a long time, over 15 years. You see things behind you in a rearview mirror.

Comment: Most simply, "in the past."

Answer (score 3):

A rearview mirror is for looking behind you when you're driving a car. So to say something is "in the rearview mirror" means that it's behind you - in this context, **in the past**.

You can check the literal definition of "rearview mirror" at [PhraseMix](http://www.phrasemix.com/phrases/a-rear-view-mirror) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rear-view_mirror), and find many metaphorical examples at [BrainyQuote](http://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/keywords/rearview.html), e.g.:

> I tend not to spend a lot of time looking in the rearview mirror. If you say, 'Oh, I did 'Hill Street Blues' or 'L.A. Law' and everything I do has to measure up to some preconceived notion of that,' it would paralyze you.

Answer (score 1):

In this context, "in the rearview mirror" is used figuratively to mean **"in the past"**.

Here is another example where it is used figuratively:

> With the midterm elections safely in the rearview mirror, Obama is on legacy patrol.

From [Obama’s One Hand Clap With Castro](http://www.thedailybeast.com/articles/2014/12/24/obama-s-one-hand-clap-with-castro.html?source=dictionary)

So in the text you've quoted, it means that he has not had a successful love life in the last 15 years.

Rearview mirror, as per [dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/rearview-mirror) literally means

> A mirror mounted on the side, windshield, or instrument panel of an automobile or other vehicle to provide the driver with a view of the area behind the vehicle

Answer (score -2):

A figurative meaning that a person has moved on and is no longer having a hold on them.

Comment: Hello, Albert. If you're going to post this as an 'answer' rather than a 'comment' (which latter action others have already taken) you need to add authoritative references here on ELU.